# datatables 1.10 draw callback and child().show vs fnOpen

Tags: jquery, datatables

im confused about behavior of drawCallback and child().show. Im using createdRow callback to open child row for parent row like this

```
"createdRow": function (row,data,index){
        if(data.child != null){
            var td = $('td', row).eq(0)
            td.addClass('details-control')
            try{
                if (showHideItems['p'+data.id] ==true){                  
                    subtablesId.push('p'+data.id)                  
                    var tr = td.closest('tr');                  
                    var nRow = this.api().row( tr );
                    var elem = format(nRow.data())
                    nRow.child(elem).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }
            }catch(err){
                //for IE
            }
        }
    }
```

and if i try to reach child row in drawCallback event, it isnt here

```
"drawCallback": function(settings){

        if (settings._bInitComplete){
            subtablesId.forEach(function(subtableId){
                try{
                    initializeSubTable($('#subtable_'+subtableId),allTasksData[subtableId])
                }catch(error){}
            })
        }

    },
```

So child rows appear after drawCallback? or am i missing something? Or is here another callback which is called at same times as drawCallback, but with child().show row visible?

Im 1.9.2 datatables, i was using fnOpen instead of child().show and new row was here in drawCallback.

Comment: Did you figure out the answer?